# How can i get the Id from the next element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the ID from the next element, but i get this - "undefined"...

What am i doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/84x9v/

HTML:

```
<a class="col" onclick="getId()">
    <div id="1"><span>1</span></div>
</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function getId(){
  var get = $(this).next("div").attr("id");
  alert(get);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the inline js

```
<a class="col">
    <div id="1"><span>1</span></div>
</a>
```

and use an event handler

```
$('.col').on('click', function() {
    var get = $(this).find("div").prop("id");
    alert(get);
});
```

note that putting a block element inside an anchor generally isn't very good practice, and the div is a **child** of the anchor, it's not the *next* sibling.

Answer (score 1):

'cause it's not the 'next' element.

```
function getId(){
  var get=$(this).find("div").attr("id");
  alert(get);
)
```

should work...

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery and `.next()` wrong. Remove the inline event handler, use `.find()` instead of `.next()`,  and try:

```
function getId() {
    var get = $(this).find("div").attr("id");
    alert(get);
}
$('a').click(getId)
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/84x9v/2/)**